# Custom dimension from Swift not populated in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

In my app, I want to track different events such as "Clicked sign in" or "Viewed friends" and pair them to a specific user by an app-generated `user_id`. Once this is done, I want to be able to view a report in Google Analytics that basically shows the following dimensions:

```
User ID, Event Timestamp, Event Action
```

First off, **is Google Analytics a good tool for this use case?**

Secondly, when I try and upload a user id as a custom dimension (I've defined it in GA with a "User" scope) via the following Swift code:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.set(GAIFields.customDimension(for: UInt(1)), value: userId)
let event : NSObject = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: category, action: action, label: label, value: nil).build()
GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker.send(event as! [NSObject: AnyObject])
```

...I can't seem to get this dimension populated in a report, even though I know it's being sent up.

**Is this the right way to send a custom dimension through the Google Analytics 3.0.3 iOS SDK?**

Comment: Use User id view to see the data ;)

Comment: yes, but I need to see the actual user ids. From what I read about the User-Id view, it will just show all users that been given a user id, but you can't actual view the id as a dimension...do you know how to go about that @Tushar

Comment: You can see the user id as a custom dimension. I see them almost everyday for different clients. I dont know how to send it via swift, But I am pretty sure that the values can be seen in GA :)